# PostgreSQL - Correct way to declare a variable

Tags: postgresql

I have the following postgresql query that was created for use in a production database to return a daily recap of counts. This query runs and returns correct results in the "staging"/test version of the database, but when run on the production db, no results are returned. I suspect it's the method I'm using to accomplish this that is ultimately causing my problems (writing to temp table, dropping on commit and selecting * from said temp table).

So my question- if there's another, better way to achieve what I'm trying to do here.. which is ultimately just to be able to declare "queryDate" as a variable and use it within the query.

A few points of interest-

- We need to be able to change the queryDate "variable" easily, as it's referenced many times throughout the script. Which is why it's declared.
- queryDate is declared as timestamp, even though we're inputting dates because that columns data type is timestamp, even though the requirement is to be able to enter a date to be used in the query. From what I've seen as well as experienced during testing, a date is a valid input for timestamp type.
- I created a table "temp_output" because without it I get "query has no destination for result data". I'm trying to emulate a temporary table in mssql/tsql. Is there a better way to do this?
- I suspect the "ON COMMIT DROP AS" portion to be causing issue here- any words on that?

Any insights are appreciated.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing, or looking for a better way to accomplish:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 

--*** MODIFY DATE TO BE USED VVV HERE *** YYYY-MM-DD format
queryDate timestamp := '2020-10-4';


BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_output ON COMMIT DROP AS
    select distinct on (queryDate)
    date(queryDate) as "Date",
    (
    select
        count(account.id)
        where date(account.created) = queryDate
    ) as "Total Registrations"
    from account
    order by queryDate;
END $$;

SELECT * FROM temp_output;
```

Here's the table you would need to test the minimal reproducable example above:

```
Table: Account

ACCOUNT.ID (PK, Integer)     ACCOUNT.CREATED (Timestamp w/ time zone)
1234                          2020-10-04 17:52:40.340573-04
3245                          2020-10-04 17:53:40.340573-04
2345                          2020-10-04 19:52:40.340573-04
5533                          2020-10-05 17:52:40.340573-04
2288                          2020-10-010 17:52:40.340573-04
```

Expected output for example:

```
Date:               Total Registrations:
10-4-2020              3
```

Here's the full query:

```
-- Daily Recap Report : 10/30/2020
-- Single row report; totals for given day.

DO $$
DECLARE 

--*** MODIFY DATE TO BE USED VVV HERE *** YYYY-MM-DD format
queryDate timestamp := '2020-10-4';


BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_output ON COMMIT DROP AS
    select distinct on (queryDate)
    date(queryDate) as "Date",
    (
    select
        count(account.id)
        where date(account.created) = queryDate
    ) as "Total Registrations",
    (
    select
        count(orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and date(account.created) = queryDate
    ) as "Total New User Orders",
    (
    select
        count(orders.id)
        from orders
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
    ) as "Total Orders",
    (
    select
        sum(order_item.quantity)
        from order_item
        join orders on orders.id = order_item.order_id
        and date(orders.placed) = queryDate
    ) as "Total Items Sold",
    (
    select
        count (distinct orders.store_id)
        from orders
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
    ) as "Cooks with Sales",
    (
    select
        cast(sum(promo_code.value) as money)
        from orders
        join promo_code on promo_code.id = orders.promo_code_id
        where date(promo_code.redeemed) = queryDate
        and date(orders.placed) = queryDate
    ) as "Promo Code Used",
    (
    select
        cast(sum(transaction.sub_total) as money)
        from orders
        left join transaction on transaction.order_id = orders.id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
    ) as "Income Total",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '01%'
    ) as "Álvaro Obregón",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '02%'
    ) as "Azcapotzalcoelse",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '03%'
    ) as "Benito Juárez",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '04%'
    ) as "Coyoacán",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '05%'
    ) as "Cuajimalpa",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '06%'
    ) as "Cuauhtémoc",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '07%'
    ) as "Gustavo A. Madero",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '08%'
    ) as "Iztacalco",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '09%'
    ) as "Iztapalapa",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '10%'
    ) as "Magdalena Contreras",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '11%'
    ) as "Miguel Hidalgo",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '12%'
    ) as "Tlahuac",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '13%'
    ) as "Tlalpan",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '14%'
    ) as "Venustiano Carranza",
    (
    select
        count (orders.id)
        from account
        inner join orders on account.id = orders.buyer_account_id
        where date(orders.placed) = queryDate
        and account.zip_code like '15%'
    ) as "Xochimilco"
    from account
    left join store on account.id = store.account_id
    left join menu on store.id = menu.store_id
    left join menu_item on menu.id = menu_item.menu_id
    left join orders on (orders.store_id = store.id)
    join store_address on store.id = store_address.store_id
    join address on store_address.address_id = address.id
    group by account.id
    order by queryDate;
END $$;

SELECT * FROM temp_output;
```

Comment: First of all: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT in particular: "_The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above)._" It seems that you want something like `select created::date, count(*) from table group by 1`

Comment: Why not do this in regular function where you can return the results w/o resorting to a temp table?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver because this query needs to be used by staff and they need to be able to run it for any date... so the date needs to be stored in a variable/constant type object so they can modify the date in 1 spot; otherwise they would need to change the date about 20+ times throughout the query

Comment: Exactly, so why not `select * from some_function(the_date)`?

Comment: @adrianklaver so the staff running it would enter/modify the date they want as an argument to the function between the ()? Pretty good idea, would you mind showing how you would implement that with the shorter example I used above?

Comment: Take a look at `RETURN QUERY` example [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) section 42.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY. Scroll down to example.

Comment: @boog. Had some time, so I posted an answer that uses the simple example(modified) above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code using your first example and changes suggested by @Abelisto:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cnt_func(cnt_date date)
RETURNS TABLE(the_date date, the_count integer)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $Body$

BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT 
        created::date, count(*)
    FROM 
        account
    WHERE
        created::date = cnt_date
    GROUP BY 
        created
    ;
END;

$Body$;


SELECT * FROM cnt_func('11/08/2020'::date);
```

Not tested but it should convey the general idea.